# What type of data is Dictionaries with equal sign between its pairs instead of (:)

Tags: python

If this is a dictionary in python:

```
Dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, ...}
```

What is this one :
I was trying the os.stat() where this pattern showed up:

```
Nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=Ol, st_nlink=0, ...)
```

i tryed to apply dictionary methods on it and it didn't work, does anybody know what is that pattern called in python and how can i get an item out of it?

Comment: Your examples are identical...

Comment: The second example is not valid Python. Can you please show a more accurate example of the problem you are facing?

Comment: Dict2 = {a=1, b=2} should give invalid syntax error

Comment: You must be seeing the `repr` version of the object, it could be literally anything.

Comment: Maybe you meant `dict(a=1, b=2)`?

Comment: Your two examples aren't the same syntax. `{foo='bar'}` is a syntax error, `thing(foo='bar')` is a call with a named parameter.

Comment: The object representation you're seeing is similar to a `namedtuple`, you can get the items out of it using either attribute or index: `x. st_mode == x[0]`. In general you can print whatever you want in `__repr__`, has nothing to do with dict syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> x=os.stat('.zlogin')
>>> type(x)
<class 'os.stat_result'>
>>> x
os.stat_result(st_mode=33152, st_ino=38797347, st_dev=64769, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=100, st_size=52, st_atime=1500747428, st_mtime=1288432638, st_ctime=1486224877)
```

As you can see (and could have checked yourself), the result of `os.stat` is an object belonging to `os.stat_result` class.

Comment: Sure i did, so you mean it is just a plain class object

Comment: Yes, and what you see is how `__repr__` method of this class renders the object.

Comment: Totally missed on that, thanks Blotosmetek